# When to sell put option

Tags: options, put-options, option-strategies

Buying a put option happens when market is going down. Correct. If that is true then when should one sell put option ?

Comment: When market is going up?

Comment: Do you mean selling to _close_ a position or selling a "short" put?

Comment: premiums are juiciest when the market is going down, so that's when I sell puts, personally. It depends on your outlook/goals.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus, market going up would be a good case for buying call option ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIC, one should sell short puts when one is willing to acquire the stock at the strike price less the premium received.  Otherwise, you might be asking for trouble.